# What does it mean to overthink?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

When does thinking of the mind becomes overthinking? and How is it different from serious and critical thinking? What are the causes of it?

Comment: good question......

Comment: The phrase over thinking is generally used when somebody contrives a complicated theory to explain something that can already be explained with knowledge common to all parties involved.